# Duplicate entry in the session table of Joomla 2.5.19

Tags: .htaccess, session, joomla2.5

Our Joomla site was hacked. Somehow attackers were able to place an `.htm` file in the root of the website and overwrite the `.htaccess` to deface the website.
I have restored a backup with the kickstart and akeeba and upgraded joomla from 2.5.18 to 2.5.19 the site already had the latest virtuemart.
Since that moment we have encountered a lot of duplicate entry errors in the session table.
Here is what I have tried so far:

- I have deleted all rows in the session table but that did not work
- I have purged sessions in the admin tool plugin

I also installed a plugin and blocked a lot of bad ip's and changed the url to the administration page. I have changed logins of admin and superusers and moved to an other host, other mysql db other ftp login and got hacked again. Have not been hacked since I blocked ips and changed the admin location. But I still have duplicate session errors and somehow a lot of `Â` characters in my content pages and no visible euro signs in virtuemart. Even though the database collation is utf-8 and I use the default htaccess which comes with joomla 2.5.19

I seriously have no idea how to troubleshoot this **joomla duplicate session** errors. Some source online says you have to remove the session table and re-create. but isn't that the same as clear all rows or a truncate?

**edit** can this be caused due to a missing column?

[image]

**edit2** the change of largetext to medium for the data column has not changed a thing, still this error:

> Duplicate entry 'cb' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO `jo_mydbprefix_session`  (`session_id`, `client_id`, `guest`, `time`, `userid`, `username`)

**edit3** can someone confirm that my problem is related to this one http://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, is 'cb' the session_id? The session ID should look more like '7b975e2584c684f199774326c77e953f', right?

However: 
are you sure your restored backup is from before the attack? I would recommend to:

- backup the whole joomla-installation
- remove all files
- unzip a pristine, new joomla-download in the www-folder
- remove the /installation-folder copy your old configuration.php to the www-folder (inspect it to see that it's OK)
- copy your template-folder to /templates, inspect all template files for hacks.

Now check if the session problem is still there.

Continue by manually downloading and copying files for your components and addons (virtuemart etc) into the file-structure.

regards Jonas

Comment: Since the site has virtuemart, I'd rather not manually install that component again and add all products and configure the store. Isn't there a php file with the session storage part which I can check and overwrite from a clean joomla 2.5.19 installation? The backup was from 2.5.18 and I have updated it to 2.5.19 so the update patch did not fix the session issue. I do not have older backups of before the attack.

Comment: Hi, you can keep the database untouched, and just manually copy the virtuemart-files into the /administrator/components- and the /components - folder. (also, copy language-files to the language-folders.)
The problem is that hackers will often leave some backdoor hidden in a random file somewhere in the installation, so it's always best to replace all files. Also check the /images-folders for non-image-files (.php-files, .pl files etc)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have verified that there are no php, pl etc. files in the images folder. the site has not been hacked for several days. But can't I just overwrite the session storage part of joomla and/or virtuemart? if so, where is it

Comment: Sorry, I dont know the exact location of the session-handling in joomla. But you can always dowload a new joomla zip-file, unpack it, and copy most of the files over your current installation(avoid copying the /installation-folder, the templates-folder and the images-folder). This will at least ensure that it is not the joomla-installation causing the problem. However, if there is some database-inconsistency causing your problem, the error will be more difficult to locate.